# How do I deploy server-side Swift on google cloud platform?

Tags: swift, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, perfect

Im interested in implementing server-side swift on Google Cloud using "Perfect". Though Im quite new to server side, some guidance in implementing this would be helpful !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing nothing about Perfect, I read [Perfect's github](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect) page and see that in runs on Linux.  Therefore, I see three ways to run Perfect on Google Cloud Platform, in order from easiest to most complicated:

1. On a Linux Virtual Machine in [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/).
2. Building a custom docker image and running it in the [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/).
3. Building a custom docker image and running it in [Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/).

If you're already familiar with Docker or Kubernetes, then options 2 or 3 may be easier for you.